# Problema al crear tabla de html desde MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy creando una tabla con datos extraídos de mi base de datos de MySql con php pero cuando quiero comenzar a mostrar los datos me marca errores como:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Safety\tabla.php on line 29
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Safety\tabla.php on line 30

Ya he revisado manuales de PHP y foros pero no logro hacer que funcione, tengo poco tiempo con PHP espero me puedan ayudar, este es mi código:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Problemas al conectar");
mysqli_select_db($con,"safety") or die("Problemas con la Base Datos");


//Se crea una tabla para mostrar los resultados


?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Tabla Reporte</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
            <caption>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Agregar
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            </caption>
            <tr>
                <td>NOMINA</td>
                <td>NOMBRE</td>
                <td>COMENTARIO</td>
            </tr>
            <?php

                $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT nomina,nombre,comentario FROM empleado,comentarios");
                $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)){

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php   echo $ver[1]    ?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
                //Cerrar la conexión
                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: este es el codigo:

Comment: Muestra tu código para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Tu consulta esta mal, si necesitas traer datos de diferentes tablas hazlo con un JOIN y al tener mal la consulta repercute en tu iteración.

Comment: Como tienes la relación de empleado con comentario?

Comment: SELECT nomina, nombre, comentario FROM empleado INNER JOIN empleado.id_empleado =  comentarios.id_empleado';

Answer (score 0):

Hola es necesario que publiques tu código para poder solucionar directamente tus errores, de cualquier forma, te paso un pequeño ejemplo de lo que intentas hacer solo es cuestión de adaptarlo a tu necesidad.

Saludos.

```
<?php
//parametros de la base de datos
$usuario='root';
$password='root';
$servidor='localhost';
$bd_name = 'nombre_bd';

// Realiza conexion
 $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $bd_name) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos'. mysqli_error());

echo('entra a conexion');

// Realizar una consulta MySQL
$consulta = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $consulta) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysqli_error());

// Imprimir los resultados en HTML
echo "<table borde='2'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Usuario</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $columna['username'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, ya publique mi codigo, si lo pudieras revisar y ver en que estoy mal

Comment: Pásame los datos de las tablas donde quieres traer los datos

Comment: seria, de la tabla empleado(nomina, nombre) y de la tabla comentarios (comentario)

Answer (score 0):

El problema veo yo que es en la siguiente línea:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT nomina,nombre,comentario FROM empleado,comentarios");
```

Estas haciendo un FROM a dos tablas. Debes hacer una sentencia SELECT por cada tabla; o bien, un JOIN  a estas dos tablas. Esta debería ser la consulta a empleado:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT nomina,nombre,comentario FROM empleado");
```

No se si el campo comentario pertenece a empleado, pero eso sería.